# Что за формат h5 нейронной сети

Tags: нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение

Есть несколько файлов с расширением h5, их мне скинули, сказав, что там содержится информация о некоторой нейронной сети, судя по названиям файлов там точно есть весовые коэффициенты. Больше информации о файлах пока нет (но мы пытаемся связаться с авторами файлов, просто они из другой страны и пока не отвечают).

Где можно прочитать описание h5-формата нейронной сети, если, конечно, это какой-то формат? И как/чем прочитать такой файл? А лучше вообще сконвертировать в формат TensorFlow или что-нибудь ещё известное...

Я даже не уверен, что этот файл полностью определяет нейронную сеть, потому что, например, в формате OpenVINO в комплекте идут 2 файла, xml с описанием архитектуры нейронной сети и отдельно бинарник с весами. А тут, возможно, только веса.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.h5` - это принятое расширение для бинарных файлов [формата "HDF5" (`Hierarchical Data Format v.5`)](https://www.hdfgroup.org/solutions/hdf5/).

Во многих высокоуровневых модулях для работы с НС (нейронные сети) существуют функции чтения/записи обученных моделей или только их весов из/в файлы формата `HDF5`.

PS [Пример сериализации модели для Python - TensorFlow/Keras...](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/keras/saving_and_serializing):

```
import keras

# create and fit the model ...

# Save the model
model.save('path_to_my_model.h5')

# Recreate the exact same model purely from the file
new_model = keras.models.load_model('path_to_my_model.h5')
```